# Combine file parts from Total Commander

Tags: files

I have an external drive formatted to FAT 32 with some files that are larger than 4 GB, so I separated them with Total Commander. Is there some way to combine them in Ubuntu?

Comment: you can successfully run total commander under Wine in Ubuntu and rejoin the file parts

Comment: Please provide information on how Total Commander splits the file. If it is a binary split, you can just `cat` the parts back together.